# sql server 2008 CTE Error

Tags: sql-server

Im trying to work with recursive CTE, but my query moves into an infinite loop. This is my code. What is the problem here?

```
With Family As 
( 
  Select s.EmpID, S.Name, s.RepID , 0 as Depth 
  From TestingRec s
  Where s.EmpID=s.RepID
  Union All 
  Select s2.EmpID,S2.Name, s2.RepID , Depth + 1
  From TestingRec s2
        Inner Join Family
        On s2.RepID = Family.EmpID

) 
Select *
From Family
```

Comment: Can you please show some sample data to clarify what the parent-child relation is like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the anchor part of the CTE:

```
Select s.EmpID, S.Name, s.RepID , 0 as Depth 
From TestingRec s
Where s.EmpID=s.RepID
```

We can see that there are rows in `TestingRec` for which `EmpID` and `RepID` are equal. In the recursive part, we select rows which match an `EmpID` that we've already found:

```
Select s2.EmpID,S2.Name, s2.RepID , Depth + 1
From TestingRec s2
    Inner Join Family
    On s2.RepID = Family.EmpID
```

However, there's nothing here to prevent us re-matching those rows that the anchor part found and adding them into the result set again, just with a new depth assigned.

The fix *may* be as simple as a `WHERE` clause in the recursive part which has `s2.RepID <> s2.EmpID`

Answer (score 1):

In your first query you get all the records where `EmpId=RepId`. When means for the initial records both empid and repid are equal.

Then in your anchor query(union all) you are refering `empid=family.repid`, which means here also you get the first query results. So i think you need to exclude the first level records in the second query. The following query might work

```
With Family As 
( 
  Select s.EmpID, S.Name, s.RepID , 0 as Depth 
  From TestingRec s
  Where s.EmpID=s.RepID
  Union All 
  Select s2.EmpID,S2.Name, s2.RepID , Depth + 1
  From TestingRec s2
        Inner Join Family
        On s2.RepID = Family.EmpID
  WHERE s2.RepID <> s2.EmpID

) 
Select *
From Family
```

Comment: this does solve my problem partially, but im still not getting my hierarchy properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
With Family As 
( 
 Select s.EmpID, S.Name, s.RepID , 0 as Depth 
 From TestingRec s
 Where s.EmpID=s.RepID
 Union All 
 Select s2.EmpID,S2.Name, s2.RepID , Depth + 1
 From TestingRec s2
 Inner Join Family
 On s2.RepID = Family.EmpID
 And s2.repid <> s2.empid --This excludes the results from the first half
) 

Select *
From Family
```